# Llenar un Select condicionado por el Select anterior

Tags: php, html, mysql, select

buenos días, primera vez que consulto en el Foro, espero no saltarme ninguna regla y que puedan ayudarme.

mi tabla:
#LISTA

- id
- lista
- cupos

tengo el siguiente código: con el cual lleno mi Select.

```
            <select class="form-control" id="lista" name="lista" required>
              <option value="">Seleccione:</option>
              <?php
              // Realizo consulta
              $query = $mysqli -> query ("SELECT * FROM lista order by lista");
              while ($valores = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
                  $lista = $valores['lista'];
              // Lleno el select con datos extraidos de la base de datos.
              echo '<option value="'.$lista.'">'.$lista.'</option>';
              }
              ?>
            </select>
```

Ahora tengo otro Select debajo que me gustaría que se llene con el valor del campo "cupos"

si en mi tabla lista el primer registro es = "Lista 1" && cupos = "4"

En el primer Select elijo Lista 1, en el segundo select me gustaría que se llene automaticamente  con

```
              <option value="1">1</option>
              <option value="2">2</option>
              <option value="3">3</option>
              <option value="4">4</option>
```

Espero puedan ayudarme, quizás es fácil pero vengo hace rato dándole vueltas.

Desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a SO en español! ¿Y que vueltas le has dado?  No veo que hayas puesto ninguna. Léete [ask] y haz el [tour] para aprender cómo funcionamos en este sitio y para evitar que tu pregunta sea votada negativamente, y [cerrada](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) porque aparentemente, aparte de dar vueltas, cosa que respeto, [no has hecho nada](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2868/por-qu%c3%a9-he-recibido-un-voto-negativo/2874#2874).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para esto amigo puedes usar Jquery para detectar cuando cambia el select y generas un Ajax que haga una petición a otro archivo PHP. A este archivo PHP le vas a mandar por el método POST el valor de la opción que seleccionaste en tu primer select. El archivo PHP externo recibirá el valor del select y hará una consulta a tu base de datos a la tabla donde este con lo que quieres rellenar el otro select. No se si me hice explicar bien, si acaso te dejo la documentacion de Ajax: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

```
//Mi primer select
<select id="primerSelect">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>

//Mi segundo select
<select id="segundoSelect">
    
</select>

//Capturar el valor del select
let opcion = $("#primerSelect").val()
 
//Detectar el cambio del select
$("#primerSelect").change( ()=>{

//Hacer petición a archivo externo de php
$.ajax({
   url: 'ruta del archivo php',
   type: 'POST',
   dataType: 'json',
   data: "valorPrimerSelect=" + $("#valorDeOpcion").val(),
})
.done(function(resultado) {
   
   //Esto te devolverá todo en un objeto JSON

   //Contar cuantos elementos hay en resultado
   let contar = Object.keys(resultado).length
   //Hacer un ciclo para agregar todas las opciones contenidas en resultado
   for (var u = 0; u < lengthGroups; u++) {
       f = u;
       //Cada iteración del ciclo agregara una opcion al select
       $("#segundoSelect").append("<option value='"+resultado[f].cupos+"'>"+resultado[f].cupos+"</option>")
}        
.fail(function() {

   console.log('Error1');  

})
.always(function() {  

});
```

Esto es lo que estaría    en mi archivo externo de PHP

```
if(isset($_POST['valorPrimerSelect'])) {
    //Capturar valor primer select
    $valorPrimerSelect = $_POST['valorPrimerSelect'];
    $traerOpciones = $connect->prepare("SELECT * FROM LISTA WHERE lista = '$valorPrimerSelect'");
    if($traerOpciones->execute()){
        $guardarOpciones = $traerOpciones->fetchAll();
        if(!empty($guardarOpciones)){
            echo json_encode($saveAuthoExist); //Esto devolvera tu resultado en un objeto json
        }else{
            echo '{}';//Si tu consulta a la base de datos no devuelve nada Ajax recibirá un objeto vacío, esto lo puedes comprobar desde la consola del navegador.
        }
    }

}
```

Quedo atento.